# How to get the array to display iterating to its children in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, observable

I am trying to get the parent and it children to array and to display it to **ngFor**.
I am facing with problem that the children will not show during the **ngFor**

I have a service which will take data from server.
This data are something like this.

```
"teaser" : [ {
"id" : "1234567",
"headline" : "Developer",
"text" : "Like Developer you will need ...",
"image" : {
  "altText" : "Code",
  "srcSet" : [ {
    "query" : "min-with: 960px",
    "path" : "randomPhoto.jpg"
  }, {
    "query" : "min-with: 320px",
    "path" : "randomPhoto.jpg"
  } ]
},
"link" : {
  "text" : "more",
  "titel" : "Job Description",
  "href" : "http://google.de",
  "target" : ""
},
"category" : [ "Job" ]
},
```

Till now I can only get the `teaser.text`but its children not to show in HTML for example: photo(path), and href with text.

This is my code

`Service`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TeaserService {

  private baseUrl = "Here is the link which is getting the Json file";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getTeaserList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`)
  }
}
```

Here is the model.

```
  export class Teaser {
  id: number;
  headline: string;
  text: string;
  image: string;
  link: string;
  category: string;
}
```

Here is the `TS` file.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public activeElement = 2;
  teasers: Observable<Teaser>;
  selectedTab = "Jobs";


  constructor(private teaserService: TeaserService) {}


  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();
  }


  reloadData() {
    this.stages = this.stageService.getStageList();
    this.teaserService.getTeaserList().subscribe(getTeasers => {
      this.teasers = getTeasers.teaser;
    });
  }
```

Here is the `HTML`.

```
div class="row" >
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" *ngFor="let teaser of teasers;">
    <img alt="" class="w-100" src="../assets/images/teaser-01.jpg"/>
    <p>{{teaser.text}}</p>
    <a class="btn-more" href="#" >
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> More</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: just to understand, the teaser.text renders correctly on the page?

Comment: @C_Ogoo Yes and I have posted a photo how do I get the array.

Comment: Your model, doesnt match the shape of the data you get from the server. So for your anchor link, the href should be: <a class="btn-more" [href]="teaser.link.href" >

Comment: @C_Ogoo That it is working but what about the image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of your object, teaser.image.srcSet is an array, so you have to iterate over this array, for example:

```
div class="row" >
 <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" *ngFor="let teaser of teasers;">
   <img alt="" class="w-100" src="../assets/images/teaser-01.jpg"/>
   <p>{{teaser.text}}</p>

   <p *ngFor="let teaserImg of teaser.image.srcSet">Image path: {{ teaserImg.path }}</p>

   <a class="btn-more" href="#" >
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> More</a>
 </div>
```

Editing as per comment. To see only the first image path:

```
<div class="row" >
 <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" *ngFor="let teaser of teasers;">
   <img alt="" class="w-100" src="../assets/images/teaser-01.jpg"/>
   <p>{{teaser.text}}</p>

   <p>First Image path: {{ teaser.image.srcSet[0].path }}</p>

   <a class="btn-more" href="#" >
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> More</a>
 </div>
```

PS: I'm not checking for null values here. This assumes all objects will have this structure, otherwise erros will be thrown in the console.

Comment: You are right but then it will get both of the photos I want only to get the first.

Comment: Do you know how to show array depends of category for example: I have category `Job`, `News` and as you can see the `json` has these categories it is possible to filter them depend from the category.

Comment: For simplicity sake, save the content of category in a new variable (like you did in this.teasers = getTeasers.teaser;), then test it in your views with *ngIf or *ngSwitch .. Documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf